# Python openpyxl: append cell values on a 2d list

Tags: python, arrays, append, 2d, openpyxl

I am currently learning Python. I am using Python35.
Basically I have an excel sheet with a fixed number of columns and rows (that contain data), and I want to save those values in a 2D list using append.

I currently saved the data in a 1D list. This is my code:

```html
import openpyxl
Values=[[]]

MaxColumn=sheet.max_column
MaxRow=sheet.max_row

for y in range (10,MaxRow):#Iterate for each row.
 for x in range (1,MaxColumn):#Iterate for each column.
  Values.append(sheet.cell(row=y,column=x).value)
    
#I have tried with the following:
Values[y].append(sheet.cell(row=y,column=x).value)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 4, in <module>
    Values[y].append(sheet.cell(row=y,column=x).value)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

```
for x in range (1,MaxColumn):
    #print(sheet.cell(row=y,column=x).value)
    Values.append(sheet.cell(row=y,column=x).value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have some code that redefines the `Values` object but in any case you can just do `list(sheet.values)`.

Comment: `list(sheet.values)` will return a list of tuple(values)

Comment: That is what is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# Define a list
list_2d = []
# Loop over all rows in the sheet
for row in ws.rows:
    # Append a list of column values to your list_2d
    list_2d.append( [cell.value for cell in row] )

print(list_2d)
```

Your Traceback Error:

```
Values[y].append(
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

`Values[y]` is not a `list object`, its a `int` value at **index  y** in your `list object`.